# Comparing NSDates to check if today falls in between

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

thanks to you guys I have successfully converted my array of strings to NSDates. Now I'm trying to check if today's date falls in between my 2 dates (namely fromDate and toDate). I've seen the following questions but failed to implement them in my code. Be great I can have any other method or help on using the solutions given by the users.

[NSDate between two given NSDates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987506/nsdate-between-two-given-nsdates)

[How to Check if an NSDate occurs between two other NSDates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072848/how-to-check-if-an-nsdate-occurs-between-two-other-nsdates)

[How can I check if an NSDate falls in between two other NSDates in an NSMutableArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293543/how-can-i-check-if-an-nsdate-falls-in-between-two-other-nsdates-in-an-nsmutablear)

This is what I currently have:

```
NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[format setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSTimeZone *tz = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
[format setTimeZone:tz];
NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSString *todaysDate = [format stringFromDate:now];
NSLog(@"todaysDate: %@", todaysDate);

//converting string - date
int size = [appDelegate.ALLevents count];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    Event *aEvent = [appDelegate.ALLevents objectAtIndex:i];

    //Convert fromDate
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
    NSDate *fromDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:aEvent.fromDate];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:tz];
    NSLog(@"fromDate: %@", fromDate);

    //Convert toDate
    NSDate *toDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:aEvent.toDate];
    NSLog(@"toDate: %@", toDate);
    [dateFormatter release];
    //Compare if today falls in between
            //codes here
    }
```

Comment: not sure I know what the question is?

Comment: To check if 'todaysDate' falls in between 'fromDate' and 'toDate'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do the following,

```
NSTimeInterval fromTime = [fromDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
NSTimeInterval toTime = [toDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
NSTimeInterval currTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
```

NSTimeInterval is basically a double type so you can compare that if currTime is greater than one and less than the other than the date falls between those two NSDates.