# NSDate past 4pm

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

Hello I have seen many NSDate comparisons on this site 
but they all seems to be very complicated , since I need only to know 
if the date now is past 4pm or before 4pm

maybe there is some easy way to achieve this goal ?

[link] ([Check if the time and date is between a particular date and time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671468/check-if-the-time-and-date-is-between-a-particular-date-and-time))

but it seems very long and complicated I just need simple bool answer past 4pm or not

```
- (BOOL)checkTime
{

    NSDate* now = [NSDate date];
    NSDate *endDate;
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    endDate = [formatter dateFromString:@"2012-12-07 16:00:00"];//well here I have a problem how do I set end day to today 4pm ?

    NSLog(@"%d",[now compare:endDate]);
    if([now compare:endDate] < 0)
         return YES;
    else if([now compare:endDate] > 0)
         return NO;
    else
         return NO;

}
```

EDIT: After the answers I came up with this code

```
- (BOOL)checkTime
{
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *df = [NSDateFormatter new];
    [df setDateFormat:@"HH"];
    int intS =9;
    NSInteger HourStart = intS;
    NSInteger hour = [[df stringFromDate:date] integerValue];
    int hourE = 16;
    NSInteger HourEnd = hourE;
    if((hour >HourStart) && (hour < HourEnd))
        return YES;
    else
        return NO;
}
```

For now it is works fine , but I am not sure it will work on another calendars set etc.

Comment: show your code and within 5 min I will help you.

Comment: yes, sorry here is my code , I need to set endDate to  today's 4 pm

Comment: @user2957713: here is the answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will give you hour:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

NSDateFormatter *df = [NSDateFormatter new];
[df setDateFormat:@"hh"];

NSInteger hour = [[df stringFromDate:now] integerValue];
```

NOTE:

If you want to check only for 4 then use `hh`, if for 16 then use `HH`.

Or in simple words `HH` for 24 hour format.

Comment: and then i should compare between 2 integers ?
i will give it a try thanks!

Comment: Worked like very well !! Thank you very much ! (I was sure there is something simpler than 4 pages of code) :)

Comment: This leaves open the question (posed in the code comments) about how you get "today at 4 PM".  For that you'll need to deal with `NSDateComponents` on `[NSDate date]`

Comment: @Eric: It depends on what is your requirement. If user need to compare only for current date, then this will work. Thats is what I solved. Otherways using NSDateComponent this can be done...

Answer (score 4):

In general, I'd prefer to use `NSDateComponents` and `NSCalendar` for these sorts of calendrical calculations, since you don't know what calendar the user is using.

Here's a method for doing the comparison in a category on `NSDate` using date components:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSDate (Foo)
- (BOOL)isAfterFourPM;
@end

@implementation NSDate (Foo)

- (BOOL)isAfterFourPM {
    unsigned int flags = NSHourCalendarUnit;
    NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:flags fromDate:self];
    return (comps.hour >= 16);
}

@end

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
        NSLog(@"is after 4 PM? - %@",([now isAfterFourPM]?@"YES":@"NO"));

        //  let's try with a different time (17h)
        unsigned int flags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit;
        flags |= NSHourCalendarUnit;
        NSDateComponents *currentComps = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:flags fromDate:now];
        currentComps.hour = 17;
        NSDate *afterFourDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:currentComps];

        NSLog(@"is after 4 PM? - %@",([afterFourDate isAfterFourPM]?@"YES":@"NO"));
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
2013-12-10 05:16:05.921 Untitled 2[43453:507] is after 4 PM? - NO
2013-12-10 05:16:05.921 Untitled 2[43453:507] is after 4 PM? - YES
```

(at ~ 5 AM Central time)

In this case, all you need to do, is get the `NSHourCalendarUnit` component from the date using the current calendar and compare the `hour` property on `NSDateComponents` to 16.

Comment: I don't get it *_* , the code you posted is not good ?
or is it good ?

Comment: Works for me.  The point I was making is that you don't need to craft a "4PM today" date solely for the purposes of making the "after 4PM" comparison.  You can make the comparison using the date components API.  See the method `isAfter4PM` above.

Comment: Oh , well I used the answer from above - "NSInteger hour = [[df stringFromDate:now] integerValue];"

so now I have an integer that holds the hour , and then I compared it to another integer that was set to 16 , 

I don't know in current time it works now , but do you think it may have problems in other time formats?

Comment: It's a simple enough comparison (just the hour), that I think it's fine as you posted in your edits.