# Notify when device date enters a date range on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, key-value-observing

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to track if the current device date is within a specific time range and get notified.

Example:

Say I have a start time of December 2, 2014 at 11AM and an end time of December 2,2014 at 1PM. I want to observe the [NSDate date] and update the UI if the current date enters the date range.

Is this possible? Can I do this with KVO?

Thanks!

EDIT: 
My question isn't about doing a check. My question is more about something like "firedate" which gets fired when I enter a time range!

Comment: See also [Check if the time and date is between a particular date and time](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10671468)

Comment: How is this question duplicate? I'm trying to keep the app open and have a notification/observer that gets fired when the clock enters this date range be actively checking.

Comment: Use `-[NSTimer initWithFireDate:interval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:]`

Comment: If you want something to happen at a certain time, you have to check what time it is.

Comment: Bneely gave me the right answer. Unfortunately, you marking this as duplicate means that I cant award him the answer.